# Equally space 3 images in a row

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have three images on [my site](http://data.vicforeststrp.opendata.arcgis.com/) that are not equally spaced apart.

I would like to space these three items evenly across the page.
I have tried adding them into a container and applying different span classes to them but with no joy.

What is the best way to solve this without causing problems elsewhere? (e.g. on smaller devices).

[image]

```
<div class="col-1 row-5 sizex-3 sizey-3">
          <a href="http://data.vicforeststrp.opendata.arcgis.com/datasets?q=HCV">
      <img src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/11426532/VicForest/HCV.png" class="img-responsive" />
    </a>
        </div>

        <div class="col-5 row-5 sizex-3 sizey-3">
          <a href="http://data.vicforeststrp.opendata.arcgis.com/datasets?q=TSZ">
      <img src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/11426532/VicForest/TSZ.png" class="img-responsive" />
    </a>
        </div>

        <div class="col-8 row-5 sizex-3 sizey-3">
          <a href="http://data.vicforeststrp.opendata.arcgis.com/datasets?q=TRP">
      <img src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/11426532/VicForest/TRP.png" class="img-responsive" />
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: are those custom classes you've assigned to your `div`s, afaik `col-1`, `row-5`, `sizex-3` and `sizey-3` are not standard bootstrap-3 classes. can you provide a http://jsfiddle.net and/or the `css` for these classes in your question please

Comment: I should point out that this site was generated by a WYSIWYG style builder that also allows you to dive into the HTML/CSS when you need more control.  So no, the code is auto generated.

Answer (score 3):

The images are not equally spaced because you have provided inappropriate column classes for second and third div's.
Use col-4 for second(instead of col-5) and col-7 for third(instead of col-8) div.

```
<div class="col-1 row-5 sizex-3 sizey-3">
          <a href="http://data.vicforeststrp.opendata.arcgis.com/datasets?q=HCV">
      <img src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/11426532/VicForest/HCV.png" class="img-responsive" />
    </a>
</div>

<div class="col-4 row-5 sizex-3 sizey-3">
          <a href="http://data.vicforeststrp.opendata.arcgis.com/datasets?q=TSZ">
      <img src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/11426532/VicForest/TSZ.png" class="img-responsive" />
    </a>
</div>

<div class="col-7 row-5 sizex-3 sizey-3">
          <a href="http://data.vicforeststrp.opendata.arcgis.com/datasets?q=TRP">
      <img src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/11426532/VicForest/TRP.png" class="img-responsive" />
    </a>
</div>
```

You might aswell want to provide extra padding to each div for small resolutions. 
Additionally, as haxxxton mentioned in comments, you should rather stick to standard bootstarp-3 classes for better usability.

Cheers!

Comment: This makes a lot of sense.  However, this does space them evenly, but not in relation to the entire horizontal width of the row, just in relation to each other.  Any idea on how to space the img equally across the entire row?

Comment: I would have suggested you to enclose all three div's (containing images) into a parent container div with style="float:none;margin:0 auto;text-align:center", but thats not working when I check on your site(probably because you aint following the bootstrap grid system completely)

For a quick-fix, you can change column classes to col-2, col-5 and col-8 for all three divs respectively.

Comment: 2,5,8 is same problem - they are equally spaced, but aligned to the righ of the page as opposed to equally spaced across the center

Answer (score 1):

You may like the reactive behaviour of a flex based solution like in this JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/6tknc03s/

```
.container {
    display:flex;
    justify-content:space-around;
    flex-wrap:nowrap;
}

.container img {
    width:100%;
}
```

I've tested this solution in Chrome, compatibility in FF and iOS requires vendor specific prefixes to be added to the CSS I've used.

Comment: This looks interesting.  Is this best practise over trying to achieve the same via Bootstrap/HTML?  Does this perhaps work on more browser versions?

Comment: I often find a pure bootstrap solution only does 85% of what I want and I end up supplementing it with my own CSS. It's not a bad practice to supplement a framework so long as you do it clearly and don't go adding supplements for every little thing you could do with bootstrap. With that said - a pure bootstrap solution would be much more browser compatible, flexbox support is spotty or non-existent on out-of-date browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to put them in `col-*-4` (I chose sm, but whatever works best for you) and make sure to add `class="img-responsive"` to the `img` element, like so:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <img src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/11426532/VicForest/HCV.png" class="img-responsive">
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <img src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/11426532/VicForest/TSZ.png" class="img-responsive">
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <img src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/11426532/VicForest/TRP.png" class="img-responsive">
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Example: http://www.bootply.com/4lmpKkgENa

Comment: This looks like the right answer, but the images stack up on top of each other when applying it within the app.  I am just trying to determine which version of Bootstrap the app is running.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out. it works i have edited your code with adding style to it.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style>
li {
display:inline;
list-style:none;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<div class="col-1 row-5 sizex-3 sizey-3">
         <ul>

         <li> <a href="http://data.vicforeststrp.opendata.arcgis.com/datasets?q=HCV">
      <img src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/11426532/VicForest/HCV.png" class="img-responsive" />
    </a>
    </li>





          <li>
          <a href="http://data.vicforeststrp.opendata.arcgis.com/datasets?q=TSZ">
      <img src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/11426532/VicForest/TSZ.png" class="img-responsive" />
    </a></li>



         <li>
          <a href="http://data.vicforeststrp.opendata.arcgis.com/datasets?q=TRP">
      <img src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/11426532/VicForest/TRP.png" class="img-responsive" />
    </a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: check this out]

Comment: Hmm, seems to stack on top of each other, let me check again.

Comment: i have inserted a printscreen in answer check it out

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
 <div class="row>
    <div class-"container">

       <div class="col-lg-4">
          <img src="">
       </div>

       <div class="col-lg-4">
          <img src="">
       </div>

       <div class="col-lg-4">
          <img src="">
       </div>

    </div>
 </div>
```